# How can i get calories data from any health band?

Tags: android, flutter, google-health

I work on some application that using calories data.

I want get this data from any health bands that can be connect to android or ios phones.

the exact problem is that i don't want use google fit api or ios health kit and i want get data directly from hardwares and no matter what company build that.

Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  You would need to individually integrate every brand of health band, as they're all completely different.

Comment: so can i get data from other applications or sdk of google?